# pymongo map-reduce not working according to the query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I have a collection:

```
{sentiment: "some_sentiment",
words: Array_of_words
}
```

I have this map function :

```
function () {
        for (var w=0; w < this.words.length; w++) {
            emit(this.words[w], 1)
        }
        
    }
```

and this is my reduce function:

```
function (word, values) {
        return Array.sum(values)
    }
```

and this is my call:

```
collection_obj.map_reduce(map_func, reduce_func, output_collection, query={'sentiment': "some_sentiment"})
```

The goal is to separate the documents by their sentiment into different collections and count the number of times a word in words_array has occurred in documents of the same sentiment.

AND THIS MUST BE DONE VIA MAP_REDUCE, DON'T SUGGEST AGGREGATE.

I am doing this via pymongo, the the code for the map function and reduce function is compiled by bson's code class, I think the problem may be with my call, idk...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it, its `query=query`, not just query